# Accessing FLV clip directly from flash player's memory under linux

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, linux-kernel

I would like to access a video clip directly from flash plugin during a RTMP transmission and save it to disk. I'm wondering **is that a sane idea** and would it be possible to build a reliable solution?

I know I can read raw memory for a process but I'm not looking for "a value" but a whole transmission. I can imagine that once a FLV frame has been read from a RTMP message and presented on a screen the plugin can free or overwrite it and there won't be anything to read (if I'm not fast enough). I'm also assuming that each chunk of a video might be stored under random address making it even more difficult/impossible to do?

What would be the best linux tool for "looking into memory" and trying to investigate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you access the process' memory you cannot extract the rtmp stream from that memory. This is because you don't know which section of the memory is used by variables or flash player internals and which region is used for the rtmp stream. Also I don't expect the rtmp to be completely in memory, but just a chunk of it at a time.

Alternative:

If you have the url of the video you can just use [`rtmpdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rtmpdump). If you don't have it already you can obtain the url using a packet sniffer like `wireshark`.

You told in comments that you've already tried that and encountered problems doing so. However, I fear that there is no way around the usage of `rtmpdump` beside the manual implementation of a rtmp client that emulates the flash player behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and yes, I know about rtmpdump and wireshark and it works but it's not what I want to achieve. I want a fully automated process which will work for 100% players. RTMPDump occasionaly requires human input (finding token for example) and in some cases doesn't work at all.

Comment: Then you might grab the raw data of the stream using a network sniffer and let flash player care about choosing the right url.

Comment: I actually created a program which pulls FLV out of a PCAP file but I can't get anything if the transmission was encrypted ;-) I'm also not sure would I be able to cover all aspects of RTMP (and related protocols). The best thing would be to let the Flash and the Player to do heavy lifting and simply copy the content without worrying about anything.

Comment: Looks like a steal to me :) Anyways I don't think this is possible.. Would love to see the results if it works!

Comment: I dug into the subject and accessing memory on linux is actually not that hard. One can read it from /proc/[mid]/mem or use gcore. I was able to find RTMP messages but I would have to understand the data structure used by the plugin. Right now it looks very unpredictable to me. The other potential idea which came to mind my was to plug into web browser though a low level API but I have no experience with that and no idea where to start.

Comment: @LukaszKujawa You have a profound technical understanding, I don't get why don't you just implement rtmp. This seems the way to go, even if there are known obstacles.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I actually have a solution based on RTMPDump implemented but it requires human interaction and is not covering 100% of cases. I created a RTMP parser which loads a PCAP file and translates it to a .FLV but it fails when a transmission is encrypted (and unfortunately most of the servers use encryption). I don't know much about RTMP encryption but I'm assuming that a key is randomly generated by a web browser and the server so a PCAP is useless for me.

Comment: You should dig more into the RTMP specification. Can you send me example urls? (unencrypted, working with your tool | encrypted, not working?) Then I could play a bit with it. (However, I don't have expertise with RTMP, but related topics I had to solve at work)..

Comment: Clone code from here https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/rtmp-assembler. In the README you have usage and links to specs. In ./feeds/ you have 2 example transmissions (one encrypted and one not). Those feeds are output of TCPFlow (script doesn't work on PCAPs directly). If you want to sniff your own transmission you have to use TCPFlow to order TCP packets. You also can't have any packet loss because you won't be able to parse it correctly.

Comment: Nice! Will have a look at this. But it will take some time to get me in.